# Property of odd degree polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

A real polynomial of odd degree has all positive coefficients . Prove or disprove the following statement----

There is a permutation of its coefficients (possibly trivial) such that resulting polynomial has exactly one real root

Comment: Anybody with the slightest idea of what can be done ?

Comment: You just wait a while, we have some pretty smart people on this site.  :)  sure someone will solve this.

Comment: Have you looked into Sturm's theorem?

Comment: How can that help in this problem ? Please help  :)

Comment: Does constant count as a coefficient ?

Comment: Yes , it does .

Comment: I have the "slightest" idea that you might want to choose a particular permutation, such as "from largest to smallest".  Or maybe "largest on the highest degree term and second largest on the x term.$  My other slight idea is that the derivative is even-degree and also has all positive coefficients.

Comment: @james_bond_007 I think I have a answer without proof. We need to put highest coeff. as constant.

Comment: Can anyone figure out what to do ?

Comment: Putting the largest coefficient as the constant does not always work.  $x^3+12x^2+47x+60$ has zeroes at $-3, -4, -5$.  The partial answer posted below suggests we need to distribute large coefficients around "both ends".

Comment: @OscarLanzi That also does not work for $x^5+100x^4+ x^3+x^2+47x+2$, which has 3 roots.

Comment: Can we use the result from    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716027/can-we-permute-the-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-so-that-it-has-no-real-roots        and then consider the derivative of the reqd.  odd degree polynomial is always positive ?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:  For the case of *cubic* polynomials it's true.

Let $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ be a cubic polynomial in $x$ with all coefficients positive and three real zeroes.  All three must be negative and they sum to $-b/a$, thus all are greater than $-b/a$.  This forces the polynomial value at $x=-b/a$ to be negative, but that  value is $(ad-bc)\over a$.

Thus $ad<bc$, but that can't be true for all permutations of a given set of positive numbers.  So at least one permutation of the coefficients fails to give three real roots.

Comment: Did we not assume here that all coefficients are positive?  That is why all real roots must be negative.